# Format cells of Excel import of csv to default to the data in csv

Tags: excel, vba, import

The data can range from none to thousands of rows with hundreds of columns.

I have created a blank Excel sheet that is set to text. Then import from a csv file. All the data is present, but some cells are rounding the data or creating scientific notation for some. The issue is some of the data will have 0 to 5 decimal places. So I cannot just select all and make it go to 5 decimals or it adds 0. Going through every cell and formatting based on the digits in the cells is tedious and prone to missing data. Also if the file is saved during the updates all other rounded fields will truncate the cell values.

What I am truly looking for is an important method or some VBA code that evaluates the `cell.value`, then formats the cell based on that value.

What is even more frustrating is the fact that most of the cell data is correct in that but there are some that round, truncate, or show scientific notation.

Comment: "Then import from a csv file" - you need to describe exactly how this is done.

Comment: Open a blank sheet
Select all cells
Format cells to text
Click data -> Get Data -> From a File -> From Text/CSV
Locate and click the CSV file for import
Click Load

The data comes in fine if you click on any cell it has all the decimal places but the cell my only show 0 to 4 of the decimal places
The problems are:
My data could have 0 to 5 decimal places so I cannot select all columns and set to 5 decimal places as that would add 0 where I do not want them so I would have to click each cell to verify the decimal places and format that one cell to match
Save truncates remaining text

Comment: It's normal for the displayed and actual value to differ, due to how cells are formatted.  I've never seen data get truncated to just the displayed value on save though - that would be a huge problem for Excel...   Does it really matter how your data is displayed (to the level of formatting individual cells in a single column) if the underlying values are correct?

Comment: I was trying to get to the root cause of the issue but I will tell you what specifically I am doing and the issues I am up against.

Comment: I have multiple CSV files that I am combining using the Get Data->From File->From Folder.  I save that file and all values are truncated to what ever was visible in the sheets. The next step in my process is to use filters to isolate the data I need. Then I use other filters to get the same data in the XML files and compare the 2 set of data. If my data from my CSV files is truncated then the compare fails and I have to go look at each failed data in the CSV file which can be extensive.

Comment: In time I will build some type of automation so I do not have to use excel at all and just parse the XML and CSV. That will take time so I am doing it manually for now.

Comment: After importing the file(s) you're saving as xlsx?  What are the XML files you're comparing to?  Can you provide a sample CSV which shows the behavior you're describing?

Comment: yes saving as xlsx sorry I can not add the data as it contains customer information but I will try to reproduce the issue with fake data

Comment: What I want is to be able to have the cell.value drive the format cells. So if there are 3 places after the decimal I want all 3 to be displayed. same if 5 are there I want all 5 to be displayed. I know I can go through them one by one but that is very time consuming. I cannot replicate the truncation issue with my current data

Comment: CSV - File1:
Reporting ID,Other party ID,Master Type,Type,Name,CCYtotal,CCY,CCYCount
N343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,I343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,HJKL,GHGH,POIU,65789.89,EUR,977779890.89078
L343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,N343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,JUYT,GHGH,,97807789890.8907,USD,675789.89
U343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,L343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,KOLM,,UYTR,78698769.897,EUR,1780899890.89078
O343JLLJ234KJ32KJ,U343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,HJKL,GHGH,POIU,656778789.8996,EUR,
F343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,O343JLLJ234KJ32KJ,JUYT,GHGH,UYTR,68786789.89,USD,1111890.89078
H343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,F343JKKJ234KJ32KJ,,YUIO,POIU,,EUR,977779890.89078

Comment: CSV - File2
Reporting ID,Other party ID,Master Type,Type,Name,CCYtotal,CCY,CCYCount
N343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,I343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,HJKL,YTYT,POIU,65739.39,EUR,977779390.39078
L343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,N343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,JUYT,YTYT,,97807739390.3907,USD,675739.39
U343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,L343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,KOLM,,UYTR,78698769.73498,EUR,1780399390.39078
O343JLLJ234KJ32KJ,U343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,HJKL,YTYT,POIU,656778739.3996,EUR,
F343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,O343JLLJ234KJ32KJ,JUYT,YTYT,UYTR,68786739.39,USD,1111390.39078
H343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,F343J4RJ234KJ32KJ,,YUIO,POIU,,EUR,977779390.39078

Comment: CSV - File3 Reporting ID,Other party ID,Master Type,Type,Name,CCYtotal,CCY,CCYCount
N343J4RJ234S432S4,I343J4RJ234S432S4,HJKL,YTYT,POIU,65766.83498,EUR,912129660.66033
L343J4RJ234S432S4,N343J4RJ234S432S4,JUYT,YTYT,,93301236960.6607,USD,675766.66
U343J4RJ234S432S4,L343J4RJ234S432S4,KOLM,,UYWQ,33698769.667,EUR,1330669660.66033
O343JLLJ234S432S4,U343J4RJ234S432S4,HJKL,YTYT,POIU,656733766.6696,EUR,
F343J4RJ234S432S4,O343JLLJ234S432S4,JUYT,YTYT,UYWQ,68336766.83498,USD,1111660.66033
H343J4RJ234S432S4,F343J4RJ234S432S4,,YUIO,POIU,,EUR,912129660.66033

Comment: those are just snippets as I cannot add the full files

Comment: Using the first file I'm not able to replicate any loss of data: after saving as xlsx and re-opening the numeric values are as they are in the csv.  Displayed values on the sheet differ according to cell format (and columns which are too narrow can trigger a scientific format) but those aren't the *actual* values.

Comment: If you select "do not detect datatypes" while importing it seems to display the data as it is in the CSV.